# How to allocate storage for each user in the cloud

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud

When developing an android app with cloud as the backend (say AppEngine), how to allocate storage space for each seperate user?

Because, all the data that is stored in the cloud will be accessible to all.

How do I manage data authorization here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. your question is too broad. show us why you think data is accesible to all, what have you tried regarding authentication?  see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

When developing an Android application you wouldn't usually access storage directly from the application. You can use cloud endpoints to send and receive information from the user to your backend, and it would be your backend the one with permission to access the storage.

There you can choose what information has the user access to. For example you could create a folder on a bucket for each user.

Here you can look at some information related to putting authorization on your cloud endpoints:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/auth